# How to change element in a matrix (2D array) using setter method?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to make my personal sudoku generator in Java, but I have a problem with setter element method of the matrix.

Field Class:

```
public void setField(int [][] field){
    this.field = Arrays.copyOf(field, field.length);
}

public int[][] getField() {
    return Arrays.copyOf(field, field.length);
}

//Change the element of the field
public void setElement (int i, int j, int n) {
    getField()[i][j] = n;
    setField(getField());
}
```

Main:

```
    // First Print
    for (i = 0; i < field.getField().length; i++) {
        System.out.println();
        for (j = 0; j < field.getField()[i].length; j++)
            System.out.print(field.getField()[i][j]);
    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Select Row");
    i = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Select Column");
    j = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Put Number");
    n = input.nextInt();

    field.setElement(i,j,n);

    // Second Print
    for (i = 0; i < field.getField().length; i++){
        System.out.println();
        for (j = 0; j < field.getField()[i].length; j++)
            System.out.print( field.getField()[i][j]);
    }
```

I don't know why the second print is the same as the first one.

Comment: i think you need to stop using `Arrays.copyOf()` as you also never assign the new copy in your `setElement()` method. Basically you create 2 separate arrays in `setElement()`. On the first you set the new value, and the second you use to set the array again

Comment: `I don't know why the second print is the same as the first one` - it's not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating copies of the matrix in the `setField` and `getField` methods

```
public void setField(int [][] field){
    this.field = Arrays.copyOf(field, field.length);
}

public int[][] getField() {
    return Arrays.copyOf(field, field.length);
}
```

Doing that in the method `setElement` you:

1. get a copy of the original matrix.
2. change an element of the copy
3. set a copy of the original matrix

Here your code with comments explaining each step:

```
 public void setElement (int i, int j, int n) {
     // 1 - Get a copy of the original matrix   
     getField() 
                // 2 - Change an element of the copy                                
                [i][j] = n;

              // 3.a - get a copy of the original matrix
     // 3.b - Set the copy                      
     setField(getField());
}
```

So the final effect doesn't change the original matrix.

You can have the desired result doing the following:

```
public void setField(int [][] field){
    this.field = field;
}

public int[][] getField() {
    return field;
}

//Change the element of the field
public void setElement (int i, int j, int n) {
    field[i][j] = n;
}
```

Comment: `So the final effect doesn't change the original matrix` - actually that's incorrect. I ran the code and it does change the original matrix. `copyOf` makes no difference in this case, since it's a shallow copy of a multi dimensional array (i.e. a copy of the outer array is created, but the copy contains the original inner arrays).

Answer (score 0):

```
// you do a copy of internal array
public int[][] getField() {
    return Arrays.copyOf(field, field.length);
}

// and then chane element of this copy
public void setElement (int i, int j, int n) {
    getField()[i][j] = n;
    setField(getField());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran your program. It is running ok. But, in the beginning, I was getting null pointer exception error. So, maybe you should consider changing following things:

1. Add `private int[][] field = new int[3][3];` in MyBean class.
2. the main() method:

   `public static void main(String[] args) {
     MyBean myBean = new MyBean();
     myBean.setElement(0, 0, 113);
     myBean.setElement(0, 1, 114);
     myBean.setElement(0, 2, 115);
     int i1,j1,n;
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     //First Print
     for (int i = 0; i < myBean.getField().length; i++) {
       System.out.println();
       for (int j = 0; j < myBean.getField()[i].length; j++)
         System.out.print(myBean.getField()[i][j]);
     }
     System.out.println();
     System.out.println("Select Row");
     i1 = input.nextInt();
     System.out.println("Select Column");
     j1 = input.nextInt();
     System.out.println("Put Number");
     n = input.nextInt();
     myBean.setElement(i1,j1,n);
     //Second Print
     for (int i = 0; i < myBean.getField().length; i++){
       System.out.println();
       for (int j = 0; j < myBean.getField()[i].length; j++)
         System.out.print( myBean.getField()[i][j]);
     }
     input.close();
   }`